# Can't get exact Unix UTC seconds

Tags: c#, date, unix-timestamp

I tried [How can I convert a DateTime to the number of seconds since 1970?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354893/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-to-the-number-of-seconds-since-1970) with

```
    DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(@"28/05/12 01:30");
    TimeSpan diff = date.ToUniversalTime() - origin;
    Console.WriteLine( (Math.Floor(diff.TotalSeconds)).ToString());
```

Output = 1338161400

It is wrong compared to
http://www.mbari.org/staff/rich/utccalc.htm
1338168600

Why ?

Comment: Timezones and/or DST, probably. See Chad's answer to the question you referenced.

Comment: I don't understand why would local time matters since number of seconds since 1970 is the same whatever the locale ?

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely from a time zone difference. If you store the values in temp variables and look, you will probably see that the `ToUniversalTime` modifies the original value appropriately:

```
        DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(@"05/28/2012 01:30:00");
        date = date.ToUniversalTime();
```

In my case, when I look at date after setting it to UniversalTime I see the time as 5:30:00 since I am on the east coast.

So, to force this to be as you expected, I just shifted my time to actually be GMT (change my date by 4 hours:

```
        DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(@"05/27/2012 9:30:00 pm");
        date = date.ToUniversalTime();
        TimeSpan diff = date - origin;
        Console.WriteLine((Math.Floor(diff.TotalSeconds)).ToString());
```

This yields: `1338168600`

Comment: OK thanks, but the input is an invariant and the algorithm should work in any country whatever its locale us or europe or asia :) It should work like the online site.

Comment: I did try origin.AddHours(-4) but result is the same ?

Comment: I rather mean date.AddHours(-4)

Answer (score 0):

The .NET `DateTime`-related classes are supposed to *Just Work*. They often do, but you have to pay attention to the details if you're working with anything but local time. (This is not a .NET-specific problem - time zones, and especially DST, often cause major headaches.) The following snippet should produce the proper output regardless of your locale:

```
DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(@"28/05/12 01:30", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
TimeSpan diff = date.ToUniversalTime() - origin;
Console.WriteLine((Math.Floor(diff.TotalSeconds)).ToString());
```

Note that for both input dates, one needs to specify explicitly that the date should be seen as a UTC date and not as a local date. The `ToUniversalTime()` call seems superfluous, but it is necessary to produce the proper difference. This seems to be an oversight in the implementation of the minus operator.

See also [Choosing Between DateTime, DateTimeOffset, and TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384267.aspx) on MSDN.