# How to create timestamp in seconds

Tags: c#, .net, timestamp, seconds

I have this task to populate this field:

> x_fp_timestamp is the timestamp created when the form is generated. It
>   is equal to the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 in UTC
>   (Coordinated Universal Time).

So what I do in C# is

```
 long ts =  DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;
```

But in that case I am getting this error:

> - x_fp_timestamp : x_fp_timestamp invalid. Not within 15 minutes of
>     present time: Thu Jan 10 21:30:25 GMT 2013. Expected 1357853425
>     plus/minus 900, but received 63493442997.

So my question is how to generate current timestamp in seconds?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354893/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-to-the-number-of-seconds-since-1970

Comment: here is a good link to look at it has so many great other examples as well Peretz [Converts a DateTime object into a unix timestamp number](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Date-Time/ConvertsaDateTimeobjectintoaunixtimestampnumber.htm)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`DateTime.Now.Ticks` [does not start at 1970](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx); try something like this instead:

```
 (DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() - new DateTime (1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds
```

Answer (score 4):

I found [DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimeseconds?view=net-6.0) to work best for my specific situation (Unity 3D [.NET standard 2.1])

```
    long timeNow = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
    string timeStamp = timeNow.ToString();
```