# ClrMD Get Memory Dump time

Tags: windbg, dump, memory-dump, clrmd

I`m playing around with [CLR Memory Diagnostics](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime) tool in order to analyze memory dumps.

Opening a dump using WinDBG, I am able to use `.time` command to get the debug session time (when dump was captured).

Does anybody knows the ClrMD API to get the date?

Comment: If you're keen on doing some of the work yourself, you can adapt the [DumpReader](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnetsamples/blob/master/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime/CLRMD/ClrMemDiag/Utilities/DumpReader.cs) class to include the SystemInfo minidump stream and get that information from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the following way to solve this task, however it restricts us to the DbgEng usage only.

1. Open dump file and specify DbgEng (so IDebugClient will be used)

   ```cs
   DataTarget.LoadCrashDump(pathToMemoryDumpFile, CrashDumpReader.DbgEng));
   ```
2. Use the `IDebugControl2` COM interface to get target time (ensure that you perform that on the same thread that started the session):

   ```cs
   uint secondsSinceUnix;
   var dbgCtrl2 = (IDebugControl2)sessionContext.DataTarget.DebuggerInterface;
   dbgCtrl2.GetCurrentTimeDate(out secondsSinceUnix);
   ```
3. Convert `secondsSinceUnix` to DateTime using the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354893/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-to-the-number-of-seconds-since-1970).
4. As output you will get UTC date time of the memory dump creation (or attaching time).

It worked well for me :)