# How to combine moment("from", "now") with timezone in a Vue binding

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, momentjs, nuxt.js

The data is pulled straight from firebase\firestore into vue\nuxt. This is the biding for the object.

So log.Created is a firebase Timespan, toDate() makes it a Date, then moment from\now turns it into "4 hours ago"

```html
<td class="py-3">{{ log.Created.toDate() | moment("from", "now") }}</td>
```

Problem is, it wasn't 4 hours ago, it was now, but UTC isn't giving me the timezone offset.

I tried setting the default timezone in a moment plugin

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueMoment from 'vue-moment'
import moment from 'moment-timezone'

moment.tz.setDefault(moment.tz.guess())

Vue.use(
    VueMoment, {
    moment,
})
```

But I think I may have some lines crossed here...

What's the missing piece of the puzzle?

More debug data

```html
<td class="py-3">
  {{ convertDate(log.Created.toDate()) | moment("from", "now") }}<br/><br/>
  {{ convertDate(log.Created.toDate()) }} <br/><br/>
  {{ log.Created.toDate() }}
</td>
```

Function:

```js
convertDate: function(date){
  return moment(date).tz(moment.tz.guess());
}
```

...and output

```
4 hours ago

Tue Oct 22 2019 17:11:59 GMT-0400

Tue Oct 22 2019 17:11:59 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Firestore's [`toDate()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp.html#todate) returns a JS `Date` object so any timezone should be irrelevant when passing it to Moment.js to format as a relative period. Where does the `moment` filter that you're using come from?

Comment: Are you 100% sure your timestamps are what you expect? `Tue Oct 22 2019 17:11:59 GMT-0400` **was** about 4 hours ago

Comment: I think you might be right and it's the conversion server side, that explains a lot... Digging into it

Answer (score 0):

Issue was the data conversion code from here
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

.AddHours(-8) was not correct

Moving to ConvertFromUnixTimestamp on this SO
[How can I convert a DateTime to the number of seconds since 1970?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354893/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-to-the-number-of-seconds-since-1970)
worked great...

Thanks for the assistance Phil