# How do I get epoch time in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, epoch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you convert epoch time in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883576/how-do-you-convert-epoch-time-in-c)

I'm trying to figure out how to get the epoch time in C#. Similar to the timestamps given on this website: http://www.epochconverter.com/

Does DateTime have a method for that?

Comment: See the Question & Answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56363742/3057246

Comment: New and better answer since .NET 4.6: use `DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()`

Answer (score 240):

```
TimeSpan t = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
int secondsSinceEpoch = (int)t.TotalSeconds;
Console.WriteLine(secondsSinceEpoch);
```

Comment: Sure, if you believe the epoch is 1970-01-01T00:00:00, like any Unix system.  But the .NET epoch is 0001-01-01T00:00:00, which is better known as `DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: Sure, but a lot of applications still use the 1970 epoch, like OAuth, for example.

Comment: @froggythefrog and SWT tokens http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh781551.aspx

Comment: isn't it supposed to be milliseconds? It's missing a few zeroes on the end

Comment: @Sinaesthetic Epoch Time is defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: @Sinaesthetic You must be used to the Java implementation, where `System.currentTimeMillis()` is the number of millis since epoch. If you're determined to use millis instead, use `long millisecondsSinceEpoch = (long) t.TotalMilliseconds;` instead.

Comment: from .Net 4.6 and above use     DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()

Comment: in first string the Epoch time is created by constructor, which returns DateTime object with unspecified kind, so use `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)` instead to avoid substraction of unspecified datetime from Utc.

Comment: @OlegSavelyev I tested your theory, and it doesn't make a difference.  My C# app is hosted with local time offset 6 hours from UTC and I get the same value either way.

Comment: @SaikatChakraborty Could you post your comment as an answer please?

Comment: @Sinaesthetic t.TotalSeconds will return in seconds only. If you want in milliseconds, you can go for t.TotalMilliseconds.

Comment: Since .NET Core 2.1 `DateTime.UnixEpoch` is equivalent to `00:00:00.0000000 UTC, January 1, 1970` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.unixepoch?view=netcore-2.1

Comment: For milliseconds in .NET 4.6 onwards: `DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()`