# What is the equivalent of NSDate's 'timeIntervalSince1970' in C#

Tags: c#

I need to store dates in a form of number of seconds since 1970.

With this I am getting number of seconds since 1970 with Swift by using Foundation's NSDate:

```
NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
```

*And maybe a dumb question but why this is `double` shouldn't it be `int`?*

What is equivalent of this method in C#?

I am not sure what to use to get the same value.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453101/how-do-i-get-epoch-time-in-c

Comment: This link may be helps: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354893/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-to-the-number-of-seconds-since-1970>

Comment: I saw those links, I just need confirmation what methods are same in both languages (to avoid getting different times)

Comment: @vacawama http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506990/cant-add-uint64-to-dictionary-of-type-string-anyobject#41506990

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TimeSpan t = (DateTime.UtcNow – new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
long timestamp  = (long) t.TotalSeconds;
```

I used the `UtcNow` property to ensure that the timestamp is the same regardless of what timezone this code is being run in.

Also, use the largest integer type you can find since the current epoch time is slightly less than 32 bit signed integer and you want code to be future proof.

#### If you do have .NET 4.6 or above, try this:

```
 DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds()
```

Comment: Is swift NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970; also UTC based?

Comment: Yes. It is UTC too. See https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdate/1416453-init

Comment: Tnx I accepted answer just have one subquestion. ToUnixTimeSeconds() returns Int but .timeIntervalSince1970 return double. Are theese both number of seconds? Do you know?

Comment: Yes. The Unix time is defined as number of seconds since 1970, 1st Jan in UTC. They use double for the same reason I am suggesting long - to avoid overflows in future.

Comment: Ah so the returned double must cast to long datatype and it is the same as .TotalSeconds then

Comment: Yes. I would try to keep the double if you build for 32 bit systems since the long on 32 bit systems isn't long enough. If you exclusively build on 64-bit machines, it's good to convert to long to avoid rounding errors common with decimal datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
(DateTime.Now - new DateTime(1970,1,1)).TotalSeconds
```

This gets the date and subtracts the default epoch time of C# `(01-01-01:00:00:00)` making it start from `01-01-1970`.

This is most probably the easiest way to get the same value.

Comment: Why are you getting miliseconds? Is swift timeIntervalSince1970 miliseconds or seconds?