# Can't add UInt64 to dictionary of type: [String : AnyObject?]

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, swift2

I am trying to make a dictionary like this:

```
func someFunc() -> [String : AnyObject?] {
    var dic = [
            "Name": someString_Variable,
            "Sum": someUInt64_Variable
        ]
```

Problem is when I add `someUInt64_Variable` I get error:

```
Cannot convert value of type UInt64 to expected dictionary value type Optional<AnyObject>
```

What to do here, I must use `UInt64` I can't convert it to `String`.
Why am I getting this error anyway?

Comment: If your dictionary is just used to map a finite set of known keys to values – you should almost certainly create a model `struct` to represent that data instead.

Comment: As always, an optional dictionary value is nonsensical because by definition a nil value indicates key is missing.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what I should do. I tried to change type to '[String : AnyObject]' but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This used to work in an earlier version of Swift when Swift types were automatically bridged to *Foundation* types.  Now that that feature has been removed, you have to do it explicitly:

You can just explicitly cast them to `AnyObject`:

```
let dic : [String: AnyObject?] = [
    "Name": someString_Variable as AnyObject,
    "Sum":  someUInt64_Variable as AnyObject
]
```

and Swift will convert them to *Foundation* types `NSString` for `String` and `NSNumber` for `UInt64`.

It might be clearer if you just cast to those types yourself:

```
let dic : [String: AnyObject?] = [
    "Name": someString_Variable as NSString,
    "Sum":  someUInt64_Variable as NSNumber
]
```

Comment: For the record, this is because there is now a difference between `Any`, which is any type, and `AnyObject`, which is any object coming from a class -- structs are not `AnyObject`s. Since `UInt64` is a struct, the conversion must be made explicit. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID342) for more info. In fact it is possible that OP would be better off using `Any` in the first place.

Comment: @BallpointBen, that has *always* been the difference between `Any` and `AnyObject`.  The Swift team just removed the automatic conversion of `String`s and `Int`s to *Foundation* types.  If you're planning on sending this dictionary to a *Cocoa Touch* framework that takes `NSDictionary`, then `[String: Any]` isn't going to cut it.

Comment: Oh, didn't realize that. Thanks.

Comment: @BallpointBen, correction to my earlier statement.  In Swift 2.3, which OP is asking about, you can't coerce `[String: Any]` to `NSDictionary`.  But, in Swift 3 this does work. Ah, the ever shifting sands of Swift...

Answer (score 0):

It’s important to understand what’s really happening here: `Int64` is not compatible to `AnyObject` because it’s simply not an object.

By bridging to Foundation types, like `someUInt64_Variable as NSNumber`, you wrap your `Int64` in an object. A new `NSNumber` object is allocated and your `Int64` is stored in it.

Perhaps you really need `AnyObject`, but normally you would use `Any` in this case:

```
func someFunc() -> [String : Any] {
    var dic = [
            "Name": someString_Variable,
            "Sum": someUInt64_Variable
        ]
```

This offers better performance (no additional heap allocations) and you don’t rely on Foundation-bridging.