# Convert epoch, which is midnight 01/01/0001, to DateTime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with a series of timestamps in it. Originally I thought they are in Unix timestamps system so I used the following code to convert them to date time.

```
big_frame['date'] = pd.to_datetime(big_frame['filename'],unit='s')
```

however, it gave me odd results so I researched a bit more and found out the timestamps are basically using the .net epoch, which is midnight 01/01/0001. So the file names are the number of seconds from that epoch. How can I convert a column in my data frame to the right DateTime?

For example if I have this

```
63730342900
```

The result should be

```
14/07/2020 17:01:40
```

Edit:

https://www.epochconverter.com/seconds-days-since-y0

This is the only site I could find that converts the above timestamp correctly

Below is the column I want to convert

```
0     63729045145
1     63729045145
2     63729045146
3     63729045146
4     63729045146
5     63729045147
6     63729045147
7     63729045147
```

Comment: I've never seen this format `01/01/0001` where did you read about .net epoch?

Comment: It's a freelancing project that I'm doing and I asked for clarification regarding the Unix files names and they said "we are using the .net epoch, which is midnight 01/01/0001." I googled a bit and couldn't really found something

Comment: For the record, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453101/how-do-i-get-epoch-time-in-c) mentioning the ".net epoch" as DateTime.MinValue

Comment: In .NET `01/01/0001` represents the smallest possible value of DateTime and is equivalent to 00:00:00.0000000 UTC, January 1, 0001, in the Gregorian calendar as stated in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.minvalue?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`01/01/0001` seems to be out of range for datetime/timedelta type. We could do a little hack like this:

```
ref_date = pd.to_datetime('14/07/2020 17:01:40')
ref_stamp = 63730342900


bigframe['date'] = pd.to_timedelta(big_frame['date'] - ref_stamp, unit='s') + ref_date
```

Output:

```
0   2020-06-29 16:32:25
1   2020-06-29 16:32:25
2   2020-06-29 16:32:26
3   2020-06-29 16:32:26
4   2020-06-29 16:32:26
5   2020-06-29 16:32:27
6   2020-06-29 16:32:27
7   2020-06-29 16:32:27
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: But I do not have the reference date, I just have a column (Question edited above) with timestamps and I want to convert those to the required timestamps

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that, if you know `63730342900` is `'14/07/2020 17:01:40'` in your format, you can use **those value** as a references.

Answer (score 3):

*While there is an accepted answer which works, I dare to suggest another solution, which might be more intuitive and less error-prone as it does not rely on specific reference values. This approach would be also generalizable to all situations.*

## Background for the solution

The time values in the question were seconds from the [`DateTime.MinValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.minvalue?view=netcore-3.1) .NET epoch, which is equivalent to 00:00:00.0000000 UTC, January 1, 0001. Fortunately, Python has also [`datetime.min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.min), which is the earliest representable `datetime` and the same as the minimum .NET epoch.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.min
Out: datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)

>>> datetime.datetime.min.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
Out: 01/01/1 00:00:00
```

## The solution

Now we can take the .NET epoch as a baseline using `datetime.min` and just add the seconds. We can also specify the desired output format.

```
import datetime
(datetime.datetime.min + datetime.timedelta(seconds=63730342900)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Which gives us the correct

```
14/07/2020 17:01:40
```

Let's extend the solution to cover the Pandas `DataFrame` in the question.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
# Create the dataframe as in the question
df = pd.DataFrame([63730342900, 63729045145,
                   63729045145, 63729045146, 
                   63729045146, 63729045146, 
                   63729045147, 63729045147, 
                   63729045147], columns = ["datetime"])
# Apply the previous formula to every cell in the column using a lambda function
df["datetime"] = df["datetime"].apply(lambda seconds: (datetime.datetime.min + datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

The result is a nicely formatted dataframe

```
    datetime
0   14/07/2020 17:01:40
1   29/06/2020 16:32:25
2   29/06/2020 16:32:25
3   29/06/2020 16:32:26
4   29/06/2020 16:32:26
5   29/06/2020 16:32:26
6   29/06/2020 16:32:27
7   29/06/2020 16:32:27
8   29/06/2020 16:32:27
```

## Learn more

Of course, Python `datetime` has also the opposite value, [`datetime.max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.max).

```
>>> datetime.datetime.max.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
Out: 31/12/9999 23:59:59
```

*Learning by stackoverflowing,*