# Get date string from count of days since Epoch C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I have an integer `15791` which represents count of days since epoch and equals 27.03.2013, how can do this convert in C#?

```
public void method1()
{
  ...
  int days_since_epoch = 15791;
  // how convert `days_since_epoch` to "27.03.2013"
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883576/how-do-you-convert-epoch-time-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adds a number of days to your epoch.

For example:

```
var epoch = new DateTime(...);  // Your epoch (01/01/0001 or whatever)
var yourDate = epoch.AddDays(days_since_epoch);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your Epoch date is in a `DateTime` just use

```
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970,1,1);

int days_since_epoch = 15791;

DateTime converted = epoch.AddDays(days_since_epoch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the [AddDays method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx), and once you got your final date, format it as usual in the `ToString()`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromDays(15791);
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).Add(ts);
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/4Y8ist)

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new DateTime(1970,1,1).AddDays(15791);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
```