# Oracle Date from Int C#

Tags: c#, oracle, date

I am querying an oracle database which has a column "Start".

My query returns a 10 digit integer in this column:

```
1369423190
1369423574
1369424520
```

My problem is converting these values back to a datetime in c#

```
start = reader.GetInt64(17);
dt = new DateTime(start);
strStart = dt.ToString();
```

This code is currently returning the following values for strStart:

```
1/1/0001 12:02:16 AM
1/1/0001 12:02:16 AM
1/1/0001 12:02:16 AM
```

What am I doing wrong here?

****Update****

I updated my code but the results are a bit off:

```
var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
l = (long)reader.GetInt64(17);
epoch = epoch.AddSeconds(l);
Start = epoch.ToString();

10/15/2056 2:46:04 PM
10/7/2273 7:46:20 PM
12/15/2403 12:21:01 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

The number stored in the database is in [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), the number of seconds since 1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM.   The .Net [DateTime constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx) you are using take ticks, which are the number of 100ns intervales since 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM.

So you need to convert from Unix time to .NET.  See [How do you convert epoch time in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883576/how-do-you-convert-epoch-time-in-c) for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var yourTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(1369423190).ToLocalTime();
```