# Google Chrome SQLite3 Insert Data

Tags: c#, google-chrome, sqlite

I am using SQLite3 library to read the Chrome's history. I am successful in reading the history however, when I try to insert the data, the data is inserted but doesn't shows up in Google Chrome's history. Here's my code to insert into History:

```
 SQLiteCommand Command = new SQLiteCommand();
 Command.Connection = Connection;
 Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO urls(url,title,visit_count,typed_count,last_visit_time,hidden,favicon_id) VALUES ('My Website','http://coolsite.com',40,30,(@Date),0,0)";
 SQLiteParameter DateParam = new SQLiteParameter("Date", DbType.Int64);
 DateParam.Value = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
 Command.Parameters.Add(DateParam);
 Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The History item is created using this code, but it won't appear if viewed in Google Chrome's History tab. The difference I find in my insertion and Chrome's insertion is the TimeStamp. Refer to the screenshot below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MSnA.jpg

Any idea on how to add the row properly and make it appear in Chrome's History tab ?

Comment: Chrome does not measure timestamps in Windows ticks. The database contains other tables which must have matching records.

Answer (score 0):

In order to enter the data properly to Chromes' tables, first you need the `@Date` parameter to fit Chrome's calculation, apparently 'webkit' format, of this parameter which is (pretty accurate):

```
long chromeTime = ConvertToUnixTime(DateTime.UtcNow) + 11644473600) * 1000000;
```

Where [Convert to Unix time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883576/how-do-you-convert-epoch-time-in-c):

```
public static long ConvertToUnixTime(DateTime aDateTime)
{
    var epochTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    return Convert.ToInt64((aDateTime - epochTime).TotalSeconds);
}
```

Along with that, the ***important*** part is to insert into 'visits' table a row with the matching `id` and eligible values, for example:

```
INSERT INTO visits(id,url,visit_time,from_visit,transition,segment_id,visit_duration) VALUES (3,50,1.305334687E+16,0,805306368,0,0)
```

If that doesn't work, try deleting the existing rows from 'urls' and 'visits' tables first.