# What's wrong with this DateTime Parser?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

This is such a Date I have from a JSON:

```
"created_time": "1383734307"
```

So my code is:

```
var myData = DateTime.ParseExact((string)item.created_time, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but I get `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: "1383734307" looks nothing like "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy".

Comment: Do you know what date `1383734307` is supposed to represent? It will help someone provide you a way of turning that number to a `DateTime` instance

Comment: I guess it's timestamp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your number `1383734307`, looks like number of seconds elapsed since `1970/01/01` *[(Unix Epoch)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)* you can do the following to get the `DateTime`

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(1383734307);
```

This will return : `dt = {06/11/2013 10:38:27 AM}`

Currently the format you are using to parse DateTime is invalid.

For your case it appears that `created_time` is of type `long/int`, since you are casting it to string, you can do:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(created_time);
```

Or you can parse it to `long` like:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(Convert.ToInt64(created_time));
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your data is not a `DateTime`, it is a timestamp. So check this question how to make `DateTime` from it: [How to convert UNIX timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa).

For c# it would be:

```
public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime( double unixTimeStamp )
{
    // Unix timestamp is seconds past epoch
    System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0);
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds( unixTimeStamp ).ToLocalTime();
    return dtDateTime;
}
```

Then, you can use `ToString` method, to generate datatime string from your `DateTime` instance, which matches your format:

```
var dateString = myDateTime.ToString("ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a Unix (seconds past epoch) Timestamp:

You need something like this

```
var dateTime = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0);
dateTime = dateTime .AddSeconds( unixTime ).ToLocalTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert from epoch time to DateTime in C#, check this answer with the code to do the conversion:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2883645/892290

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(long.Parse((string)item.created_time));
```