# What is the correct way to convert Epoch/Unix time to .NET DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime, epoch

Based on the [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-microsoft-json-date/2316066#2316066) I received, I am converting epoch time to .NET DateTime by doing the following:

```
 string unixDate = "/Date(1395780377459)/";
 var datestring = unixDate.Substring(6).TrimEnd(')', '/');
 var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
 var result =  epoch.AddMilliseconds(long.Parse(datestring));
```

It is giving the correct result. But the code seems hacky to me. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice. Improve the old one.

Comment: Maybe `var dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>("\"" + unixDate + "\"");`

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. Could you please explain why do you think this is a duplicate?

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but not necessarily of that question..

Comment: Consider: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883576/how-do-you-convert-epoch-time-in-c (but leaves out the /Date/ aspect; also JS dates are not Unix-epoch dates.)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate but it *is* off-topic (belongs on CodeReview at a push). Also, I don't see how this is hacky.