# DateTime integer value in C# and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime

I am using a web service which returns me JSON data.

one of the value in that JSON data is datetime.

1421788745000 - This is the value returned for that datetime field.

When I tried to convert that value into DateTime (using below code), it returns me 01/02/0001 3:29:38 PM.

```
 foreach(dynamic jResult in jsonResult["twtDetails"])
                    {                        
                        DateTime date = new DateTime(long.Parse("1421788745000"));
                        DateTime dt = new DateTime(createdAtTime);
                    }
```

But when I tried to parse the same value using following javascrit code (using this site - http://jsfiddle.net/ ), I got a valid date : Tuesday 20th Jan 2015

```
alert(new Date(1421788745000).toUTCString());
```

Can somebody tell me what is the correct C# code for this ?

Comment: Related: [How do you convert epoch time in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883576/how-do-you-convert-epoch-time-in-c) Though, JavaScript timestamps are in [milliseconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmilliseconds.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some magic with the year 1970, as far as I remember.

Try this:

```
public DateTime ConvertDate(long unixTime)
{
    var date= new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    return date.AddSeconds(unixTime);
}
```

Maybe, you may take a deeper look at [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for C# `DateTime` and JavaScript `Date` are different.  JavaScript `Date` expects milliseconds since the "Unix Epoch" of 1/1/1970.  This code should work for you in C#:

```
    var dt = new DateTime(1970,1,1).AddMilliseconds(1421788745000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize method?

Comment: This would be better as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I used JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize. But I dont want to create a data contract to build the response...and I used dynamic instead. So the datetime field is coming as string.