# DataMember Property with Custom Get?

Tags: c#, json, rest, properties, datacontract

[I'm going by this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674188.aspx) and trying to figure out how to have a DataMember without an auto property. Basically I have a field is a date time in epoch format and I want the property to be a DateTime so I'm trying to do the conversion in the property's get. I'm not sure how to format this exactly.

Since Code was requested please look at the following. :

```
// The date looks like this in the JSON 
"someEpochDateTime": 1428785212000,

// I thought I could work around it using the following code, however
// I get a warning saying someEpochDateTime is never set.

[DataMember(Name = "someEpochDateTime")]
private long someEpochDateTime;

public DateTime test
{
get { return DateTimeConverter.FromUnixTime(someEpochDateTime); }
}
```

Using [FromUnixTime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2883645/1970794)

Comment: Here's how to do the conversion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883576/how-do-you-convert-epoch-time-in-c.  Call this code in the `DateTime` getter and setter

Comment: Show your current code, please.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Updated to add some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my last edit actually works as a solution, I just get a compiler warning for some reason.

```
[DataMember(Name = "someEpochDateTime")]
private long someEpochDateTime;

public DateTime test
{
    get { return DateTimeConverter.FromUnixTime(someEpochDateTime); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this you can create datereturn property this will return date

```
     [DataContract]
     public class Mycontractclass
     {     
         // Apply the DataMemberAttribute to the property.
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime datereturn
        {
           get
           {
              return this.dateCreated.HasValue
                 ? this.dateCreated.Value
                 : DateTime.Now;
           }

           set { this.dateCreated = value; }
        }

        private DateTime? dateCreated = null;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but how do you do this as a DataMember in a DataContract is what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @user1970794 Add Attribute to your class and property see edit