# Convert epoch date with KnockoutJS and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

My ASP MVC controller returns the results of the database in Json and the date field in epoch:

```
public ActionResult List(int id)
{

    IEnumerable<object> query = (from a1 in db.Persons
                                 where a1.personID == id
                                 select new
                                 {
                                        personID = a1.personID,
                                        date = a1.Date,
                                        Firstname = a1.Firstname,
                                        Lastname = a1.Lastname,

                                 }).ToList();

    return Json(query);
}
```

The Jquery result:

```
{firstName:'James',lastName:'Smith',date:"/Date(1447110000000)/"},
{firstName:'Susan',lastName:'Smith',date:"/Date(1447110000000)/"},
....
```

See more at: http://jsfiddle.net/EZUEF/749/

I tried to do it in the controller with:

```
date = a1.Date..ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

It does not work. What is the best solutions to convert the Epoch date to dd/mm/yyyy? In KnockoutJS or in the controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert epoch time in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883576/how-do-you-convert-epoch-time-in-c)

Comment: Sorry, I just realised it's not being posted in, it's being returned.. whoops.  However, I would do the conversion on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/).

```
data-bind="text: moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY')"
```

jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5kzn1v6f/1/)