# Getting an Epoch Time Value on Visual Test of Silk Test

Tags: silktest

I'm having a hard time to have an active data for the calendar date on my system. I am using Visual Test on SilkTest, and I have noticed that whenever I am clicking a value from the calendar, I'm getting a @time property. And that time property contains the Epoch Time format.

So whenever I try to playback the script, there are instance that I will get an error where Silktest cannot locate the selected date on the recording. Do you have any idea on how can I convert the Epoch time to its specific value?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to put your content quality up

Comment: Can you change the XPath manually, e.g. to ...//DIV[@time]?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert epoch time in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883576/how-do-you-convert-epoch-time-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Use the identify tool to see whether there are other properties that you can use to identify the control instead of using the @time value.