# Convert Google Play Reviews lastModified seconds to DateTime

Tags: google-api, google-play-developer-api

I  need to process Google Play customer reviews as described in https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews and https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/reply-to-reviews.
The documentation shows

```
"lastModified": {
          "seconds": long,
          "nanos": integer
        },
```

Example

```
"lastModified": {
          "seconds": "1452114723",
          "nanos": 913000000
        },
```

- `comments[].developerComment.lastModified`

  - nested object
  - The last time * at which this comment was updated.
- `comments[].developerComment.lastModified.nanos`

  - integer
- `comments[].developerComment.lastModified.seconds`

  - long

Can anyone give me  a hint how to convert seconds/nanos to normal date/time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out that seconds in Google documentation means Unix epoch time (Epoch beginning 1/1/1970).

To convert to time you can use FromUnixTime extension from
  [How do you convert epoch time in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883576/how-do-you-convert-epoch-time-in-c/7844741#7844741).

I didn't expect that Google has such bad documentation and do not care about feedback( [Where to submit Google play developer api feedback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018102/where-to-submit-google-play-developer-api-feedback))

Answer (score 0):

For java/joda time the time is in milli seconds hence will require to be multiplied by 1000.

```
DateTime seconds = new DateTime(1452114723 * 1000L);
```