# Reading the installation date of the C# OS

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core-3.1, regedit, dword

With the C# Core 3.1 WinForms application, the first installation date of the operating system cannot be read through regedit. It gives different results than the date given by "SystemInfo" command with CMD.

**CMD "System Info":**

[CMD Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y46tQ.png)

Original Install Date: 11/26/2022, 1:08:26 PM

**C# Read a "Regedit InstallDate(DWord)":**

[Regedit Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKQk0.png)

Date: "1.01.1601 00:02:46"

[C# Read a Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeLDJ.png)

```
RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, computerName);
key = key.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", false);
if (key != null)
{
    DateTime installDate =
        DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(
            Convert.ToInt64(
                key.GetValue("InstallDate").ToString()));

    return installDate;
}
return DateTime.MinValue;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value in `InstallDate` is not a FILETIME value, but a Unix Time (seconds since 1970-01-01).
You can use

```
var installDate = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(regValue);
```

to convert to a `DateTimeOffset`.

For other conversion methods see [How do you convert epoch time in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883576/how-do-you-convert-epoch-time-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

[@KlausGutter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75347015/16563198) is spot on, the value in the registry is a Unix time. If you want to convert it to a `DateTime` rather than a `DateTimeOffset`, then you could use something like

```
var installDate = DateTime.UnixEpoch.AddSeconds(regValue)
```